# SyncAdapter onPerformSync does not get called

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am developing an offline-first app that uses a SyncAdapter to load the data to a webserver. Basically, the data is saved to a local SQLite database using greenDao library. Everytime data is added or deleted, I call the `performSync()` method so it gets synced with the webserver. My problem is, that `onPerformSync()` never gets called.

I am new to this concept and am still learning, so there are a few things that are not clear to me.

I have implemented `StubAuthenticator`, `StubAuthenticatorService`, `StubProvider`, `SyncAdapter` and `SyncService` as it is done in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter).

I was not clear about the `accountType`. In the documentation, they say:

> The sync adapter framework requires each sync adapter to have an account type, in the form of a domain name. The framework uses the account type as part of the sync adapter's internal identification. For servers that require login, the account type along with a user account is sent to the server as part of the login credentials.
>   If your server doesn't require login, you still have to provide an account type. For the value, use a domain name that you control. While the framework uses it to manage your sync adapter, the value is not sent to your server.

My server does not require login, but i am not sure what to pass to the `accountType` attribute.

`Repository` class for database functions:

```
public class UnicornRepository {

    private static String AUTHORITY = ".sync";
    private static String ACCOUNT = "dummyAccount";
    private static String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "unicorns.com"; //Not sure about this

    private static UnicornRepository instance;

    private Account mAccount;

    private UnicornRepository(Context application){
        mAccount = createSyncAccount(application);
    }

    public static UnicornRepository getInstance(Context application) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UnicornRepository(application);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void addUnicorn(Unicorn unicorn) {
        //Add unicorn to database
        sync();
    }

    public void deleteUnicorn(Unicorn unicorn) {
        //Delete unicorn from database
        sync();
    }

    private Account createSyncAccount(Context context) {
        Account account = new Account(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null); //returns false
        return account;
    }

    private void sync() {
        ContentResolver.requestSync(mAccount, AUTHORITY, Bundle.EMPTY);
    }
}
```

`accountManager.addAccountExplicitly()` returns false, so the account can't get logged in. Is that the reasen `onPerformSync()` does not get called? If yes, what should i pass to `accountType`?

I am not sure if that is enough information. If you need some more infos, I can add them.

**EDIT:**
I just found out that the account gets logged in, so this is not the problem. The problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: *If yes, what should i pass to accountType*  -  The same as in `<sync-adapter/>`

Comment: Yes but what should i pass to it in `sync-adapter`? Is that important? `unicorns.com` does not exist, I just put it in there because I didn't find out what to actually put there.